# States if India not displaying in dropdown list during checkout process in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, magento, checkout

Sorry for posting existing problem, but my problem is quite different to others.

my requirement is, during checkout process when customer choose India as country then the state/province list will display as dropdown list. But except few countries like United State, Germany, Canada etc. the state list is not displaying.

I update the following two tables "directory_country_region" and "directory_country_region_name" by Indian states. Please check the following queries --

```
NSERT INTO `directory_country_region` (`region_id`, `country_id`, `code`,     
`default_name`) VALUES
(485, 'IN', 'ANDRA', 'Andra Pradesh'),
(486, 'IN', 'ARUNA', 'Arunachal Pradesh'),
(487, 'IN', 'ASSAM', 'Assam'),
(488, 'IN', 'BIHAR', 'Bihar'),
(489, 'IN', 'CHAND', 'Chandigarh'),
(490, 'IN', 'CHHAT', 'Chhattisgarh'),
(491, 'IN', 'DADAR', 'Dadar and Nagar Haveli'),
(492, 'IN', 'DAMAN', 'Daman and Diu'),
(493, 'IN', 'DELHI', 'Delhi'),
(494, 'IN', 'GOA', 'Goa'),
(495, 'IN', 'GUJAR', 'Gujarat'),
(496, 'IN', 'HARYA', 'Haryana'),
(497, 'IN', 'HP', 'Himachal Pradesh'),
(498, 'IN', 'JK', 'Jammu and Kashmir'),
(499, 'IN', 'JHARK', 'Jharkhand'),
(500, 'IN', 'KARNA', 'Karnataka'),
(501, 'IN', 'KERAL', 'Kerala'),
(502, 'IN', 'LAKSH', 'Lakshadeep'),
(503, 'IN', 'MP', 'Madya Pradesh'),
(504, 'IN', 'MAHAR', 'Maharashtra'),
(505, 'IN', 'MANIP', 'Manipur'),
(506, 'IN', 'MEGHA', 'Meghalaya'),
(507, 'IN', 'MIZOR', 'Mizoram'),
(508, 'IN', 'NAGAL', 'Nagaland'),
(510, 'IN', 'ORISS', 'Orissa'),
(511, 'IN', 'PONDI', 'Pondicherry'),
(512, 'IN', 'PUNJA', 'Punjab'),
(513, 'IN', 'RAJAS', 'Rajasthan'),
(514, 'IN', 'SIKKI', 'Sikkim'), 
(515, 'IN', 'TAMIL', 'Tamil Nadu'),
(516, 'IN', 'TAMIL', 'Tripura'),
(517, 'IN', 'UP', 'Uttar Pradesh'),
(518, 'IN', 'UTTAR', 'Uttaranchal'),
(519, 'IN', 'WB', 'West Bengal');
```

and the other is --

```
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region_name` (`locale`, `region_id`, `name`) VALUES
('en_US',485,'Andra Pradesh'),
('en_US',486,'Arunachal Pradesh'),
('en_US',487,'Assam'),
('en_US',488,'Bihar'),
('en_US',489,'Chandigarh'),
('en_US',490,'Chhattisgarh'),
('en_US',491,'Dadar and Nagar Haveli'),
('en_US',492,'Daman and Diu'),
('en_US',493,'Delhi'),
('en_US',494,'Goa'),
('en_US',495,'Gujarat'),
('en_US',496,'Haryana'),
('en_US',497,'Himachal Pradesh'),
('en_US',498,'Jammu and Kashmir'),
('en_US',499,'Jharkhand'),
('en_US',500,'Karnataka'),
('en_US',501,'Kerala'),
('en_US',502,'Lakshadeep'),
('en_US',503,'Madya Pradesh'),
('en_US',504,'Maharashtra'),
('en_US',505,'Manipur'),
('en_US',506,'Meghalaya'),
('en_US',507,'Mizoram'),
('en_US',508,'Nagaland'),
('en_US',510,'Orissa'),
('en_US',511,'Pondicherry'),
('en_US',512,'Punjab'),
('en_US',513,'Rajasthan'),
('en_US',514,'Sikkim'),
('en_US',515,'Tamil Nadu'),
('en_US',516,'Tripura'),
('en_US',517,'Uttar Pradesh'),
('en_US',518,'Uttaranchal'),
('en_US',519,'West Bengal');
```

Although I updates these two tables with Indian states but neither no states are displaying in the billing information during checkout nor any other place like editing of address of customer.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can add like this for india

```
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` VALUES
(NULL , "IN", "Andaman Nicobar","Andaman Nicobar"),
(NULL , "IN", "Andhra Pradesh","Andhra Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Arunachal Pradesh","Arunachal Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Assam","Assam"),
(NULL , "IN", "Bihar","Bihar"),
(NULL , "IN", "Chandigarh","Chandigarh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Chhattisgarh","Chhattisgarh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Dadra Nagar Haveli","Dadra Nagar Haveli"),
(NULL , "IN", "Daman Diu","Daman Diu"),
(NULL , "IN", "Delhi","Delhi"),
(NULL , "IN", "Goa","Goa"),
(NULL , "IN", "Gujarat","Gujarat"),
(NULL , "IN", "Haryana","Haryana"),
(NULL , "IN", "Himachal Pradesh","Himachal Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Jammu Kashmir","Jammu Kashmir"),
(NULL , "IN", "Jharkhand","Jharkhand"),
(NULL , "IN", "Karnataka","Karnataka"),
(NULL , "IN", "Kerala","Kerala"),
(NULL , "IN", "Lakshadweep","Lakshadweep"),
(NULL , "IN", "Madhya Pradesh","Madhya Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Maharashtra","Maharashtra"),
(NULL , "IN", "Manipur","Manipur"),
(NULL , "IN", "Meghalaya","Meghalaya"),
(NULL , "IN", "Mizoram","Mizoram"),
(NULL , "IN", "Nagaland","Nagaland"),
(NULL , "IN", "Orissa","Orissa"),
(NULL , "IN", "Pondicherry","Pondicherry"),
(NULL , "IN", "Punjab","Punjab"),
(NULL , "IN", "Rajasthan","Rajasthan"),
(NULL , "IN", "Sikkim","Sikkim"),
(NULL , "IN", "Tamil Nadu","Tamil Nadu"),
(NULL , "IN", "Tripura","Tripura"),
(NULL , "IN", "Uttar Pradesh","Uttar Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Uttaranchal","Uttaranchal"),
(NULL , "IN", "West Bengal","West Bengal");

INSERT INTO `directory_country_region_name` (`locale` ,`region_id` ,`name` ) SELECT 'en_US', tmp.region_id, tmp.default_name FROM `directory_country_region` AS tmp WHERE tmp.country_id='IN';
```

And for more detail just go throw [magento commerce link with SQL](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/198398/)

Also here is one [more blog](http://dploy.in/2012/adding-states-in-india-to-magento/)

hope this will solve your issue

Comment: Thanks liyakt, I already did it, but my actual problem is I can't see any state dropdown list in the billing information when select India as country during checkout, it simply display the blank text box only. But for US, Canada, Germany it display the drop down list for states.

Comment: also in admin as one setting also require state

Comment: yes, also clear the browser cache and magento cache and in the admin panel I select India as required state.

Comment: please check with your layout file and ajax call in billing phtml

Comment: I have used 2col-right layout and it seems ok, but how do I check ajax call?

Comment: in file you have to check for country code initialization to call ajax on change of country code as india

Answer (score 0):

i m sure this will help u.
please copy all your sql script to the following table:

1. change table `directory_country_region` to `hsdirectory_country_region`
2. change from table `directory_country_region` to `hsdirectory_country_region_name`

or just run the query as below:

```
INSERT INTO `hsdirectory_country_region` (`region_id`, `country_id`, `code`,     
`default_name`) VALUES
(485, 'IN', 'ANDRA', 'Andra Pradesh'),
(486, 'IN', 'ARUNA', 'Arunachal Pradesh'),
(487, 'IN', 'ASSAM', 'Assam'),
(488, 'IN', 'BIHAR', 'Bihar'),
(489, 'IN', 'CHAND', 'Chandigarh'),
(490, 'IN', 'CHHAT', 'Chhattisgarh'),
(491, 'IN', 'DADAR', 'Dadar and Nagar Haveli'),
(492, 'IN', 'DAMAN', 'Daman and Diu'),
(493, 'IN', 'DELHI', 'Delhi'),
(494, 'IN', 'GOA', 'Goa'),
(495, 'IN', 'GUJAR', 'Gujarat'),
(496, 'IN', 'HARYA', 'Haryana'),
(497, 'IN', 'HP', 'Himachal Pradesh'),
(498, 'IN', 'JK', 'Jammu and Kashmir'),
(499, 'IN', 'JHARK', 'Jharkhand'),
(500, 'IN', 'KARNA', 'Karnataka'),
(501, 'IN', 'KERAL', 'Kerala'),
(502, 'IN', 'LAKSH', 'Lakshadeep'),
(503, 'IN', 'MP', 'Madya Pradesh'),
(504, 'IN', 'MAHAR', 'Maharashtra'),
(505, 'IN', 'MANIP', 'Manipur'),
(506, 'IN', 'MEGHA', 'Meghalaya'),
(507, 'IN', 'MIZOR', 'Mizoram'),
(508, 'IN', 'NAGAL', 'Nagaland'),
(510, 'IN', 'ORISS', 'Orissa'),
(511, 'IN', 'PONDI', 'Pondicherry'),
(512, 'IN', 'PUNJA', 'Punjab'),
(513, 'IN', 'RAJAS', 'Rajasthan'),
(514, 'IN', 'SIKKI', 'Sikkim'), 
(515, 'IN', 'TAMIL', 'Tamil Nadu'),
(516, 'IN', 'TAMIL', 'Tripura'),
(517, 'IN', 'UP', 'Uttar Pradesh'),
(518, 'IN', 'UTTAR', 'Uttaranchal'),
(519, 'IN', 'WB', 'West Bengal');

INSERT INTO `hsdirectory_country_region_name` (`locale`, `region_id`, `name`) VALUES
('en_US',485,'Andra Pradesh'),
('en_US',486,'Arunachal Pradesh'),
('en_US',487,'Assam'),
('en_US',488,'Bihar'),
('en_US',489,'Chandigarh'),
('en_US',490,'Chhattisgarh'),
('en_US',491,'Dadar and Nagar Haveli'),
('en_US',492,'Daman and Diu'),
('en_US',493,'Delhi'),
('en_US',494,'Goa'),
('en_US',495,'Gujarat'),
('en_US',496,'Haryana'),
('en_US',497,'Himachal Pradesh'),
('en_US',498,'Jammu and Kashmir'),
('en_US',499,'Jharkhand'),
('en_US',500,'Karnataka'),
('en_US',501,'Kerala'),
('en_US',502,'Lakshadeep'),
('en_US',503,'Madya Pradesh'),
('en_US',504,'Maharashtra'),
('en_US',505,'Manipur'),
('en_US',506,'Meghalaya'),
('en_US',507,'Mizoram'),
('en_US',508,'Nagaland'),
('en_US',510,'Orissa'),
('en_US',511,'Pondicherry'),
('en_US',512,'Punjab'),
('en_US',513,'Rajasthan'),
('en_US',514,'Sikkim'),
('en_US',515,'Tamil Nadu'),
('en_US',516,'Tripura'),
('en_US',517,'Uttar Pradesh'),
('en_US',518,'Uttaranchal'),
('en_US',519,'West Bengal');
```

after succeed, dont forget to clear and refresh magento cache in the admin panel.

Comment: why we need to change the table name?

Comment: change table directory_country_region to hsdirectory_country_region ??